# How to define class instances per unit test?

Tags: python, class, python-unittest, python-class

I have the following class, and I would like to write several unit tests for it:

```
class JsonSchemaValidator:
    def __init__(self, json_file):
        self.json_file = json_file
        self.schema = json.load(open(json_file))

    def check_json_schema(self):
        print(self.json_file)
        Draft3Validator.check_schema(self.schema)
```

As shown above, the class has two instances of `self.json_file` and `self.schema`, and I would like to define the schema per test. How can I set up the tests, so schema can be defined per test case?

```
class TestValidator(TestCase):
    def test_check_json_schema1(self):
        schema = {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key1": {"type": "string"}
            },
        }
        actual = JsonSchemaValidator.check_json_schema() ##??
        self.assertIsNone(actual)

    def test_check_json_schema2(self):
        schema = {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key2": {"type": "SOME_TYPE"}
            },
        }
        self.assertRaises(SchemaError, JsonSchemaValidator.check_json_schema, schema) ##??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want your code to actually `open` a file on the disk and `load` it, you want to simply provide the result.
One way to do that is to **mock** the `open` and `json.load` references that `TestValidator` uses, like that :

```py
import json
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mocking


class JsonSchemaValidator:
    def __init__(self, json_file_path):
        self.json_file_path = json_file_path
        self.schema = json.load(open(json_file_path))

    def check(self):
        print(self.json_file_path)
        # do the validation here


class TestValidator(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_check_json_schema1(self):
        schema = {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key1": {"type": "string"}
            },
        }
        with mocking.patch("builtins.open"), \
                mocking.patch.object(json, "load", new=mocking.Mock(return_value=schema)):

            validator = JsonSchemaValidator("/blah")
            print(validator.schema)  # exactly what we wanted : {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'key1': {'type': 'string'}}}

            # do your test here
            validator.check()
            ...
```

You can check by adding `print(json.load, open)` to `JsonSchemaValidator.__init__`, you will get something like :

```
<Mock id='139724038827840'> <MagicMock name='open' id='139724039146992'>
```

because they have been mocked while you were in the context manager (`with`).

(I renamed `json_file` to `json_file_path` because I think it makes things more clear)

Comment: @Marc did it solve your problem ?